# How can i diseable information block in prestashop 1.6?

Tags: prestashop, block, prestashop-1.6

Please i have a problem with informations block.
 It shows two blocks and i want to diseable it please.
 I can't find when i can do it.
 Thanx
 Ps : here's a screenshot : 
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable the 'CMS block' (or blockcms) module from your admin panel.